# Can Django admin lists / widgets be used outside admin pages?

Tags: python, django

The admin lists are so powerful and have so many built in functionalities, so I'd like to display them outside on the standard http://site.url/admin/ urls.  Is there a way to reuse the list widget on my own custom templates?

For example, say I have a list of blog entries, that I just wanted non-logged in users to just view .  I don't want them to have any access to the admin section, but want to just display the list that the admin site shows with all the sorting, pagination and automatic model related display functionality that comes with django admin out of the box.

I know I can create my own templates to do this, but I just want to replicate the exact functionality provided by the admin module so am thinking there must be a way to reuse django's admin lists and include it in my own template since Django.  I've googled this quite a bit but haven't had any luck yet finding a answer to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to use e.g. the `django.contrib.admin.views.main.ChangeList` class in a view of your own?

Comment: That's perfect.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!